# Android Map Zooming to the current location when app loading do not working in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to write a code which has a Map Zooming to the current location when the application loading.

Here is the code I use to zoom the map.

```
  //Zoom to the current location
    public Location getMyLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
        if (location != null)
        {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }

        return location;
}
```

Then I called the method inside `onCreateView` of the Fragment.
Here is that code.

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(!isGooglePlayServiceAvailable())
        {
           return null;
        }

        if(rootView != null)
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)rootView.getParent();
            if(parent != null)
            {
                parent.removeView(rootView);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.google_maps, container, false);
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();


            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet"));

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            if(bestProvider != null)
            {
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
                if(location != null)
                {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
            }

        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

But, my code doesn't seem to execute this zooming part.

I'm kind of new to Android and this is the first code I'm using in fragment(I'm telling this because this may be a low level question to advanced people). So, can someone please  tell me is there any specific way to implement fragments?

Thanks in advance. :)

-edit -

Here is my `GoogleMapsFragment.java`

```
public class GoogleMapsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements LocationListener {

    View rootView;
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);

    private GoogleMap map;

    public GoogleMapsFragment()
    {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(!isGooglePlayServiceAvailable())
        {
           return null;
        }

        if(rootView != null)
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)rootView.getParent();
            if(parent != null)
            {
                parent.removeView(rootView);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.google_maps, container, false);
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();


            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet"));

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            if(bestProvider != null)
            {
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
                if(location != null)
                {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
            }

        }

        return rootView;
    }

    //Zoom to the current location
    public Location getMyLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
        if (location != null)
        {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }

        return location;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // Identify the current location of the device

        Location currentLocation = getMyLocation(); // Calling the getMyLocation method
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServiceAvailable()
    {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
        if(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before returning the view, you're calling zooming part. So, it will be never visible to you. Just Move the animateCamera of zooming code to onActivityCreated, or on Resume or in any method after onCreateView

Comment: I added my whole fragment. Can u b more specific? Kinda new to Android. So, no idea how some methods work. :( thanks :)

Comment: Add a new method in your class named as onActivityCreated. If you're using Android Studio, click anywhere with-in your class not in inside methods then press ALT + Insert key > Override Methods. This will show you the list of all of the available methods for overriding. Then select onActivityCreated. Then move your map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); and 
Location currentLocation = getMyLocation(); lines to this method. Also, make sure to check null pointer for map.

Comment: Before diving in to checking your code, I see that you are using `getMap()`, which is already deprecated. Are you perhaps following a specific tutorial? I suggest to look into the latest implementation first ([quickstart here](https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-android)). There you can see the difference, and the suggested to use methods like `getMapAsync()`. Plus, after making the quickstart run, you can just go ahead and modify the code the way you want it to. Cheers! :)

Comment: Hi  Yasir Tahir, did what you told here. Please see my edited answer. Still no luck :(

Comment: Thanks for your help McAwesomville. I agree with u and I need to properly learn this first. But, I'm kind of in a hurry. So, I need to make this by tomorow. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** implement interface

```
implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

**2.** Add

```
 private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;  
 private GoogleMap mMap;
 private LatLng latlng;
```

**3.** Add this code in `onCreateView` Method

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    if (mapFragment != null)
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);  

 if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
```

**4.** `OnMapReady` Method

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

//        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 3000, null);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    }
```

**5.** `Override` method `onConnected`

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mLastLocation != null)
              latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            return;
        }
      //call onMapReady override method
     onMapReady(mMap);
    }
```

**6.**

```
 @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I implement OnMapReadyCallback? I added my whole GoogleMapsFragment.java. Can you tell me where to put this code?  TRhanks. :)

Comment: if you implement OnMapReadyCallback then automatically this override method generate

Comment: Hi, your code kind of working. :D  But, it is not zooming to my current locaton though. It is zooming to the where marker is located. :(

Comment: Hi I'm trying to several things to change  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(6), 5000, null); to my current location. Still no luck. :(

Comment: hey sorry for late replay,  check my edited answer. it will zoom on last current location. and also don't forget to add google play service in gradle and delclaration in manifest. hope it will work for you. best luck Quality Products

Comment: Oh! Thanks I'll try this. :)

Comment: Hi, I cannot resolve mActivity in onCreateView, marker_map and sydney in onMapReady and checkSelfPermission, mActivity and location in onConnected :(

Comment: I used getActivity to resolve the same problem in getSystemService. But, Here i can't. Can u edit ur answer? I'm really sorry for bothering. :(

Comment: if you compile your project api level 23 then it's working o/w remove condition

Comment: Changed compileSdkVersion to 23. Still cannot resolve. I'm tired of trying. :(

Comment: then please remove this condition. it's necessary on marshamallow.

Comment: U mean remove ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity() ?

Comment: Anywy, u helped me upto this point and Im glad u did. I'll accept this answer since your answer can zoom the map. I'll open another question for this. Thanks. :)