# How to get current accurate location using GPS provider?

Tags: android, gps, location, currentlocation

i need current location of user with the help of GPS provider.
Currently i'm getting GPS location, but in some devices i'm not getting location.

I also tried last known location and network location, but they are not accurate.

So please help by providing better solution.

My current code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            if (getActivity() == null){
                return;
            }
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> fromLocation = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                Address address = null;
                if (fromLocation != null && fromLocation.size() > 0) {
                    address = fromLocation.get(0);
                    final String locality = address.getLocality();
                    if (dataSend != null) {
                        dataSend.onDataSend(address);
                    }

                    fragmentMapBinding.map.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            googleMap.clear();
                            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(latLng, 19, 0, 0));
                            googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
                            googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
                            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Your Location"));
                        }
                    });
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.e(TAG, "getMap", e);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s + " : " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
```

Comment: I'm not Java guy, but I'm quite certain about gaining location via mobile network. Is it possible to check if no location obtained by GPS, switch using mobile data as a location provider?

Comment: Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429706/android-map-zooming-to-the-current-location-when-app-loading-do-not-working-in-f/37429950#37429950. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Use Fused Location APi which will provide accurate location on it's own.
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: Your code for getting a location is fine.  Either the user has disabled GPS, or you're just not able to get a satellite fix.  Neither of which you can do anything about.